# objective-c: how to convert an int to NSString

Tags: objective-c

I am using the following code to get an alphabetic number of a first letter in a string:

```
toupper([ my_string characterAtIndex: 0 ] ) - 'A'
```

I need to do an inverse task - to convert an alphabetical number of a letter to a NSString.

What is the best way to do so?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please consider renaming the title to use the word "character" instead of "NSString" since "int to NSString" implies how to convert an int value (e.g. 3) to a string value (e.g. @"3").

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`stringWithFormat:`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat:):

```
// 0 ==> @"A", 25 ==> @"Z"
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", theCharIndex + 'A'];
```

edited to include string identifier @